# symfony 4.4 sonata admin and sonata user compatible issue

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I tried to install symfony 4.4 instead. after the installation, I tried to install sonata user bundle and got this error:
The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.
then I followed this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49034641 to create fos_user.yaml
and I got this error:
The service "fos_user.mailer.default" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating".
then I followed this link
FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle#2679 (comment)
and I got this error:
The service "sonata.user.admin.user" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.manager.orm".
and I followed this link:
#1050 (comment)
and I got this error:
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_user" (in "/fsys1/home/public_html/mycel7/config/packages/fos_user.yaml"). Looked for namespace "fos_user", found ""framework", "sensio_framework_extra","twig", "web_profiler", "monolog", "debug", "maker", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security", "twig_extra", "knp_menu", "sonata_doctrine", "sonata_twig", "sonata_form", "sonata_block", "sonata_exporter", "sonata_admin","sonata_doctrine_orm_admin"" in /fsys1/home/public_html/mycel7/config/packages/fos_user.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/fsys1/home/public_html/mycel7/config/packages/fos_user.yaml").
at this step I am not sure what to do then.

This is my config/packages/fos_user.yaml :
`fos_user: db_driver: orm  firewall_name: main user_class: Entity\User from_email: address: "test@gmail.com" sender_name: "test"`

This is my config/packages/framework.yaml:
`framework: secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%' session: handler_id: null cookie_secure: auto cookie_samesite: lax #esi: true #fragments: true php_errors: log: true templating: engines: twig`
symfony version is 4.4.
other files are un-touched

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Gray, I have updated the code I had. I installed in a new environment. only configured fos_user.yaml and framework.yaml